# Get Access to the first element of an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

```
def main():
    reading = read_file();
    display(reading);

def read_file():
    with open('extra.txt') as fp:#read file
        lines = fp.read().split();
    fp.close(); #close file
    return lines; #return lines to main function

def display(info):
    print info;


main();
```

The code above returns:

```
['2,3', '1,2,3', '4,5,6', '2,3', '10,11', '13,14,15', 'END']
```

I need to be able to access the 2 and the 3 in the beginning by themselves. Is there a way I can split the array so that each number is separated by a comma and is its own element? Those number were orginally printed as:
2,3
1,2,3
4,5,6
2,3
10,11
13,14,15
END

and using the .split() function I split it into the array. If I try and use a for loop it gives me an error because they are strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John's answer is perfect, just in case you need to convert it to an array

```
z = []
sample = ['2,3', '1,2,3', '4,5,6', '2,3', '10,11', '13,14,15', 'END'];
[[z.append(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in sample]
```

and you can get the first 2 values by using `z[0:2]`

So your code should be something like

```
def main():
    reading = read_file();
    display(reading);

def read_file():
    with open('extra.txt') as fp:#read file
        lines = fp.read().split();
    fp.close(); #close file
    return lines; #return lines to main function

def display(info):
    z = []
    [[z.append(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in info]
    print z;       # prints ['2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '2', '3', '10', '11', '13', '14', '15', 'END']
    print z[0:2];  # prints ['2', '3']


main();
```

Comment: @AMcCauley13 From my understanding, you just want to print the first element `2, 3` split by comma, if that is the case, you can just modify the `print` statement in `display` to `print info[0].split(',')`

Answer (score 2):

To enable access of the `2` and `3` separately, try:

```
>>> s = '2,3 1,2,3 4,5,6 2,3 10,11 13,14,15 END'  # input from file
>>> s.replace(',', ' ').split()
['2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '2', '3', '10', '11', '13', '14', '15', 'END']
```

Or, if you want to keep the grouping from your original code and just access the elements one by one:

```
>>> c = s.split()
>>> c
['2,3', '1,2,3', '4,5,6', '2,3', '10,11', '13,14,15', 'END']
>>> c[0].split(',')
['2', '3']
```

#### In your code

```
def main():
    reading = read_file();
    display(reading);

def read_file():
    with open('extra.txt') as fp:#read file
        s = fp.read()
    # No explicit close for fp because it is closed automatically by `with` statement.
    return s.replace(',', ' ').split()

def display(info):
    print info;

main()
```

Comment: @AMcCauley13 In the code above, we use  `s.replace`  where `s` is a string, not a list.