# splitting an array of string into individual elements

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

```
['2,3', '1,2,3', '4,5,6', '2,3', '10,11', '13,14,15', 'END']
```

Instead of how this array looks now, I need it to look like this:

[2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,etc...]

I also cannot figure out, or even if there is a way to, separate the array of strings so that they are not strings and instead integers.

This is my read method and how it separated my txt file

```
def read_file():
    with open('extra.txt') as fp:#read file
        lines = fp.read().split();
    fp.close(); #close file
    return lines; #return lines to main function
```

Comment: This homework problem has been asked before:  [Get Access to the first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760688/get-access-to-the-first-element-of-an-array/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Access to the first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760688/get-access-to-the-first-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one go with a [*list comprehension*,](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the strings by comma and `int()` to convert to integers:

```
In [1]: l = ['2,3', '1,2,3', '4,5,6', '2,3', '10,11', '13,14,15', 'END']

In [2]: [int(number) for item in l[:-1] for number in item.split(",")]
Out[2]: [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]
```

`l[:-1]` to skip the last `END` element.

Also, here is a way to read and wrap the head around nested list comprehensions:

- [How to read aloud Python List Comprehensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061760/how-to-read-aloud-python-list-comprehensions)

Comment: see above for an edit on how I am reading the file into my program

Answer (score 0):

If your **old_list** is your list containing the above strings,

```
old_list.remove('END')
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    sp = i.split(',')
    for j in sp:
        new_list.append(j)
```